# Oracle 11g SQL to split column data as mutiple column data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where data is as below

```
ID            Date                 Comments
101         23/Jun/2018      RR: Insufficient resource
101         23/Jun/2018      Next week apply for leave 
102         22/Jun/2018      NULL
103         21/Jun/2018      Go ahead
```

I need a Oracle sql to fetch above data as

```
ID     DATE          A_comments                    D_comments
101   23/Jun/2018    Next week apply for leave      RR: Insufficient resource
102   22/Jun/2018
103   21/Jun/2018     Go ahead
```

Whenever comment is with prefix RR: it should go to `D_comments` and without prefix RR it should go to  `A_comments` for a particular ID.

Help me to achieve this.

Comment: What if there is more than one row with (or without) an RR prefix for the same ID? Or there is only one of each but they are on different dates?

Comment: we can have only one comment with RR prefix for an ID. But without RR prefix we can have mutiple Comments. In that case,  we can append all comments

Comment: Your welcome! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This query works for your sample data. But, if there are any other unknown scenarios as mentioned by Alex, please edit your question to add it.

```
SELECT
    id,
    date_t,
    MAX(
        CASE
            WHEN comments LIKE 'RR:%' THEN NULL
            ELSE comments
        END
    ) a_comments,
    MAX(
        CASE
            WHEN comments LIKE 'RR:%' THEN  comments
        END
    ) d_comments
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    id,
    date_t;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11d3e04/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can "distribute" columns based on the value with the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT id, 
       date,
       case when comments not like 'RR:%' then comments end as A_comment,
       case when comments     like 'RR:%' then comments end as D_comment
  FROM my_table;
```

The output would be

```
ID     DATE          A_comments                    D_comments
101   23/Jun/2018    Next week apply for leave     
101   23/Jun/2018                                  RR: Insufficient resource
102   22/Jun/2018
103   21/Jun/2018    Go ahead
```

Therfore, you need to "fold" the columns into one row, for instance with `MAX`:

```
SELECT id, 
       date,
       MAX(case when comments not like 'RR:%' then comments end) as A_comment,
       MAX(case when comments     like 'RR:%' then comments end) as D_comment
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY id, date;
```

which would generate

```
ID     DATE          A_comments                    D_comments
101   23/Jun/2018    Next week apply for leave     RR: Insufficient resource
102   22/Jun/2018
103   21/Jun/2018    Go ahead
```

**EDIT:**

To reflect your comment, to append all comments, you could use `LISTAGG` instead of `MAX`:

```
SELECT id, 
       date,
       LISTAGG(case when comments not like 'RR:%' then comments end, '-'
                           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY comments)) as A_comment,
       MAX(case when comments like 'RR:%' then comments end) as D_comment
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
 WITH t
     AS (SELECT 101 id_col,
                '23/Jun/2018' date_col,
                'RR: Insufficient resource' comments
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 101 id_col,
                '23/Jun/2018' date_col,
                'Next week apply for leave' comments
           FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 102 id_col, '22/Jun/2018' date_col, 'NULL' comments FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 103 id_col, '21/Jun/2018' date_col, 'Go ahead' comments
           FROM DUAL)
(  SELECT id_col,
          date_col,
          MAX (CASE WHEN comments NOT LIKE 'RR:%' THEN comments END)
             a_comment,
          MAX (CASE WHEN comments LIKE 'RR:%' THEN comments END) d_comment
     FROM t
 GROUP BY id_col, date_col)
ORDER BY id_col
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7da3d9/2)